# Connecting to a Microsoft SQL Linked Server (DB2) using JDBC?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, neo4j, db2, linked-server

I have a Windows 10 machine with a local installation of Microsoft SQL Server (Express). Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I have created a linked server which is using an OLE DB connection to a Db2 database which is running on an IBM i machine.

I am trying to use an ETL tool (specifically a Neo4j ETL tool) to connect to the linked server. This ETL tool is running on my Windows 10 machine - I can successfully get it to connect to the locally-hosted SQL Server databases but I have yet to find a way to get it to connect to the linked server through SQL Server. Is it possible to establish a connection to a Microsoft SQL Linked Server using a JDBC connection? It would seem to me that if it is possible, there would have to be some form of intercommunication between JDBC and OLE DB.

Also - because it is likely someone will ask - I am not simply connecting to the Db2 database directly from the ETL tool because the ETL tool doesn't seem to work properly with a Db2 database hosted on an IBM i. My thought was, perhaps I could cheat the system a bit by targeting the ETL against an SQL server but more specifically to a linked server that the SQL server is connected to.

Comment: Better to ask a new question to get neo4j working directly to Db2-for-i, either with a licensed IBM-driver, or via jt400 driver. "Does'nt seem to work properly" is not a problem description.

Comment: You will always be connecting to SQL Server and never to the DB2 server. The statements you execute on SQL Server can selectively be remoted to the DB2 server using the various syntaxes available for linked sources (four-part name, `EXECUTE ... AT`, `OPENQUERY`) but you cannot pretend, for the benefit of the JDBC connection, that it's actually talking directly to the DB2 server. Effectively, SQL Server will operate as a (non-transparent) proxy. Consider creating views that access the remote objects and targeting those. If that fails, supply more details on what goes wrong.

Comment: @mao Apologies for the vagueness in regards to the issues with the Neo4j ETL tool, but I figured that the exact nuances and descriptions of that particular problem don't really have a bearing on my question here. For what it's worth, I've reached out on the community forums and the GitHub issues page in an effort to determine a solution to the problem and I will continue to do so, but for the time being, I'm considering other ways of achieving what I want.

Comment: @FillardMillmore I'm a little unclear in what you are trying to do - are you trying to connect Neo4j to SQLServer?

Comment: @Lju I'm trying to use the Neo4j ETL GUI tool to connect to a linked server (in which the link is stored on the SQL Server and the linked server is an instance of Db2 on an IBM i machine)